# Why doesn't this time conversion from UTC to local code work?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: event!)

        dateFormatter2.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        let dateString = dateFormatter2.string(from: date!)

        let finalDate = dateFormatter2.date(from: dateString)
        return finalDate!
```

I have sports events that give me string dates in UTC which I am trying to convert into local time. This code is similar to the dozens of examples given in this site when asked this question, yet it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the format of your event.

Comment: What is the input and the actual and expected output? Why do you convert String -> Date -> String -> Date? And please note that `Date` describes an absolute point in time and **has no timezone**.

Comment: @Daniel No, do not quote the `Z` in the formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the iso8601 formatter :

```
static let iso8601: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
    return formatter
}()
```

This turns your string into a `Date`.

You will need to add the time difference, most likely through `TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent`

Comment: Can you explain how I can add the time difference? Do I do it after I make the date from a string, or before?

Comment: Well you can first, in the code I showed you, change the time zone to TimeZone.autoUpdatingCurrent then add TimeZone.autoUpdatingCurrent.daylightSavingsTimeOffset()